# Use array as object keys

Tags: javascript

Following is my object:

```js
let body = {
  size: 0,
  aggs: {
    colour: {
      terms: {
        size: 10000,
        field: "brand_name.keyword",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and by traversing above object I make array of keys

```
let kys = ["aggs", "colour"]
```

Now I want to access my object and add new object after the colour. My question is how I can use the array `kys` to access `colour` in above object `body`.

I mean I want to add the following empty object:

```
body["aggs"]["colour"]["newkey"] = {}
```

But I don't want to hardcode keys define in kys.

Thanks

Comment: Is Lodash [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) an option? `_.get(body, kys)`.

Comment: Can you add what you've already got / tried ?

Comment: an object "after" colour? You mean inside aggs? Note that an object should not be assumed to have properties in a certain order.

Comment: you could store kys as a hashmap with references to the objects.

Comment: I am not following you @user120242

Comment: @Nicolas I am looking a way

Comment: Your question is vague, what do you mean by "add new object after the colour" ? You want "aggs" to be a list of object ?

Comment: when you get to kys.push("colour"), do kys["colour"] = node.colour, that way kys["colour"] will point to the colour object.  Or if you want an array, kys.push(["colour",node.colour]), so when you iterate over the array kys[i][0] is the key name and kys[i][1] is a reference to the object you want.

Comment: let me edit my question

Comment: @Dony this is what I want, I mean I want to add object body["aggs"]["colour"]["newkey"] = {}. But I dont want to hardcode keys define in kys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a function similar to [`lodash.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get), which gets a deeply nested value from a string or array of keys. For your example you could do any of the following:

```
const colour = _.get(body, kys);
// which is the same as:
const colour = _.get(body, ['aggs', 'colour']);
// which could also be written:
const colour = _.get(body, 'aggs.colour');
```

It's also fun to write your own `get` function, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP.

EDIT: There is also a [`lodash.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) method which will set a deeply nested value. It would look something like this:

```
let kys = ['aggs', 'colour'];
let kys2 = kys.slice(0, -1).concat('coulor2');
_.set(body, kys2, { foo: 'bar' });
// which is the same as:
_.set(body, ['aggs', 'colour2'], { foo: 'bar' });
// which could also be written:
_.set(body, 'aggs.colour2', { foo: 'bar' });
```

Comment: I need a set method which you define above

Comment: So one of the things that will make you a good programmer is to see something like `_.get` and automatically say to youself _"if there is a `get` method which does what I need, maybe there's a `set` method which also does what I need"_. Indeed there is: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set

Answer (score 0):

There's the array syntax for JavaScript objects:

```js
let body = {
  size: 0,
  aggs: {
    colour: {
      terms: {
        size: 10000,
        field: "brand_name.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

let kys = ["aggs", "colour"]

body[kys[0]].colour2 = {
  terms: {
    size: 10000,
    field: "brand_name2.keyword"
  }
}

console.log(body)
```

Comment: it can be more then 2 keys. kys length can be change its not fixed. I don't want to hardcode any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the problem statement, this:

```
body["aggs"]["colour"]["newkey"] = {}
```

will result in the following `body`:

```js
{
  size: 0,
  aggs: {
    colour: {
      terms: {
        size: 10000,
        field: "brand_name.keyword"
      },
      newkey: {},  // the addition
    },
  }
}
```

Given that you have array `kys === ["aggs", "colour"]`, the following will insert a property named "newkey", with value an empty object `{}`, into the property named "colour":

```
body[kys[0]][kys[1]].newkey = {}
```

Comment: Yes exactly is the output I am looking for